# How to get nested two values from nested select ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**Query:**

```
 SELECT business.bussId,
 (select count(invoices.userId) from invoice where invoice.userId = '3000' ) 
 as invoiceCount,    
 (select SUM(invoices.price) from invoice where invoice.userId = '3000' )
 as invoiceprice ,
 FROM business WHERE business.bussId=100
```

How could I get invoice price and invoiceCount using one nested select ?

Comment: can you put your tables here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the subquery to the `from` clause:

```
SELECT b.bussId, i.invoiceCount, i.invoiceprice
FROM business b cross join
     (select count(i.userId) as invoiceCount, SUM(i.price) as invoiceprice
      from invoice i
      where i.userId = '3000'
     ) i
WHERE b.bussId = 100;
```

You can actually write this without the subquery, but your question is specifically about using subqueries.

That form would be:

```
SELECT b.bussId, count(i.userId) as invoiceCount, SUM(i.price) as invoiceprice
FROM business b left join
     invoice i
     on i.userId = '3000' and b.bussId = 100
GROUP BY b.bussId;
```

Comment: thank new for you answer, no, I don't want to use left join, what does cross join do ?

Comment: A `cross join` creates a cartesian product between the two tables.  When one of the tables has just one row (as is presumably true in this case), it just adds the extra columns to the result set.